# How to correctly add a variable's value to parameters in Postman?

Tags: twitter-oauth, postman

I'm learning Chrome Postman now and my issue now is:

**I need to generate a new value of a parameter for each request.**

So each request (I make a POST) must have a unique value of this parameter.

**So far I thought to manage it with environment variables and I have done it like this:**

1. I add a new environment variable with a unique value
2. I use this variable in the "value" field on a parameter

[image]

**And it doesn't work** - I get error 401 Authorization Required.

Seems that the error is not connected to the parameter at all but as soon as I change the parameter and manually input a unique data it works well!

**So this will work for me:**

[image]

Please suggest what I'm doing wrong here and advice how to do it right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent some more hours investigating I found my problem!

The problem is the value I put into a variable - it included ":" sign and this sign simply changed my URL.